# Pass list of objects in GET Request for Spring REST using REST Client

Tags: java, json, get, spring-restcontroller, advanced-rest-client

I want to pass list of object i.e. user object which has userId and viewDateTime fields. How we can generate the get URL to hit the service from REST client ?

**USER POJO :**

```
public class User implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6407485814769754843L;

    private String userId;

    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_ONLY)
    private Date viewDateTime;

    public String getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }

    public void setUserId(String userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }

    public Date getViewDateTime() {
        return viewDateTime;
    }

    public void setViewDateTime(Date viewDateTime) {
        this.viewDateTime = viewDateTime;
    }
}
```

**REST Controller :**

```
@RequestMapping(value = APIConstant.GET_ALL, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public NotificationResponse getAll(@RequestParam("notificationType") NotificationType notificationType,
            AppCodeDTO appCode, @RequestParam(value = "clientDetails", required = false) ClientDetails clientDetails,
            UserListWrapper userlist, @RequestParam(value = "createdByUserId", required = false) String createdByUserId,
            @RequestParam(value = "eventDateTime", required = false) Date eventDateTime,
            PagableSortable pagableSortable) throws QHPlatformException {
        return null;
    }
```

**Wrapper Class :**

```
public class UserListWrapper {

    @JsonSerialize(converter=UserConverter.class)
    private List<User> users;

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

}
```

Can we pass it using UserWrapper class or if we can pass List as request param in controller. Please let me know how to build the URL for GET Request.

Thanks